# Map two domains to single Azure website like www.client1.example.com and www.client2.example.com

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

How we can map two or more domains to a single Azure website?

So in my website, I can map some logic based on domain name.

Like: `www.client1.example.com` & `www.client2.example.com`

Comment: Just make one domain point to the website. Then redirect every other domains to the first one. You can either redirect or just mask. By masking I mean you redirect without changing the URL.

Comment: are you able to map two or more domains to a Azure app now?

Answer (score 0):

> How we can map two or more domains to a single azure website

You could try to use a CNAME record to map to your Azure app's default domain name, and Azure app service enables us to assign more than one hostname to site. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name) shows how to map custom domain name to Azure app, please refer to it.